# ClientWebSocket Alternative That Can Access HTTP Response Headers in Server Handshake Response?

Tags: c#, .net, websocket, clientwebsocket

I am developing a WebSocket client application using C#/.NET.

Up until this point, I have been using the class *System.Net.WebSockets.**ClientWebSocket*** to implement the client.

Unfortunately, I recently discovered that *System.Net.WebSockets.ClientWebSocket* does not provide the ability to access the HTTP response headers found in the handshake response received from the WebSocket server when connecting (an open issue related to this can be found [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/28331)).

Can anyone recommend an alternate WebSocket client class/library that supports all of the following:

1. SSL mutual authentication;
2. Set HTTP request headers in handshake request sent to WebSocket server; and
3. Get HTTP response headers in handshake response received from WebSocket server.

I am currently using Visual Studio Professional 2022 (17.0.6). Thanks in advance.

Comment: Additional Note: We are currently using .NET 5 and are soon moving to .NET 6.